# Is there an alternative to OAuth to use Google Drive API to upload to Google Drive?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to write code in C# to upload files into Google Drive and the only way that I've found that I could do that is by going through Google's Dev Console and setting up credentials. Since the point of my project is so that other users can easily upload a file from the application into their Google Drive account, is there an option that would allow for this to happen without having to go and manually configure their API?

Comment: Have you tried exploring [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview)? Google picker API can be used in your web apps to let users open or upload Drive files.

Comment: I haven't heard of it but I will check it out. Thanks.